# OpenVPN : Access to client from LAN machines

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have set up a Pritunl Vpn Server.

I have multiple client which connect to it. Once connected, the client can access to the other machine in the same LAN as the VPN server. From the VPN Server I can also access to all clients.

The only missing piece, I don't manage to achieve due to my lack of linux networking skills is how access to the client machine from the other machine in the LAN.

I tried to SSH etc but there are no route to the host. I assume I should add a route to it which pass throught the VPN server, but I don't know how.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly clear on what you want to accomplish, but it sounds like site-to-site.  OpenVPN is very good at this, it will use iptables on the server to establish the correct routes, but first you have to setup a vpn gateway using a client config and iroute.

OpenVPN uses client profiles/configs to let the server know that where to route traffic, site to site configs are know different.

This is a good article that explains the steps.
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans